# Extract date as UNIX timestamp from already heavily formatted SQL datetime string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following piece of SQL code that does the following:

1. Obviously looks at a datetime field (stored every 5 minutes)
2. Averages and rounds above-mentioned datetime field to hour.  The result looks like this:

   ```
   2012-02-11 16:00:00.000
   2012-02-11 17:00:00.000
   2012-02-11 18:00:00.000
   2012-02-11 19:00:00.000
   ```

And here's the code:

```
DATEADD(hh, DATEPART(hh, LogDetails.lastupdated), 
DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, LogDetails.lastupdated), 0)) AS TimePeriod
```

This works like a charm and the related objects average out just fine. I now need to turn this datestamp into UNIX Timestamp (for Flot charting purposes).  Can someone help a bit here?  Whatever I seem to be doing isn't working, all the UNIX timestamps come in the same.

**EDIT:**  This is finally working !!

```
DATEDIFF(second, '1970/01/01 00:00:00', 
DATEADD(hh, DATEPART(hh, LogDetails.lastupdated),
DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, LogDetails.lastupdated), 0))) as UXTIME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Example:

```
DECLARE @gmtOffset AS INT = DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()); 
DECLARE @someDates TABLE (d DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @someDates(d) VALUES('2012-02-11 16:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @someDates(d) VALUES('2012-02-11 17:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @someDates(d) VALUES('2012-02-11 18:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @someDates(d) VALUES('2012-02-11 19:00:00.000');

SELECT DATEADD(second, @gmtOffset, d) AS time_in_gmt,
       DATEDIFF(second, '1970/01/01 00:00:00', DATEADD(second, @gmtOffset, d)) AS unix_timestamp
FROM @someDates;
```

Comment: @J Cooper, I've tried several variations of this already with no luck :).  Could you expand on your answer a bit?  I know the syntax for converting to UNIX time stamp is correct, I just cannot get it to convert the formatted and aggregated TimePeriod value

Comment: Interesting, I see what you mean... I'm looking into this

Comment: @mynameisneo - i posted a working example using your sample data